# Cannot find a valid baseurl for repo : base problem

Tags: centos, networking, curl, repository

I am trying to update yum but with no success. I have tried all existed solution and i cannot fix it 
This is the error I get

[root@localhost ]# yum update
    Loaded plugins: fastestmirror, langpacks
    Loading mirror speeds from cached hostfile
    Could not retrieve mirrorlist http://mirrorlist.centos.org/?release=7&arch=x86_64&repo=os&infra=stock error was
    14: curl#7 - "Failed to connect to 2001:1b48:203::4:10: Network is unreachable"

```
 One of the configured repositories failed (Unknown),
 and yum doesn't have enough cached data to continue. At this point the only
 safe thing yum can do is fail. There are a few ways to work "fix" this:

     1. Contact the upstream for the repository and get them to fix the problem.

     2. Reconfigure the baseurl/etc. for the repository, to point to a working
        upstream. This is most often useful if you are using a newer
        distribution release than is supported by the repository (and the
        packages for the previous distribution release still work).

     3. Run the command with the repository temporarily disabled
            yum --disablerepo=<repoid> ...

     4. Disable the repository permanently, so yum won't use it by default. Yum
        will then just ignore the repository until you permanently enable it
        again or use --enablerepo for temporary usage:

            yum-config-manager --disable <repoid>
        or
            subscription-manager repos --disable=<repoid>

     5. Configure the failing repository to be skipped, if it is unavailable.
        Note that yum will try to contact the repo. when it runs most commands,
        so will have to try and fail each time (and thus. yum will be be much
        slower). If it is a very temporary problem though, this is often a nice
        compromise:

            yum-config-manager --save --setopt=<repoid>.skip_if_unavailable=true

Cannot find a valid baseurl for repo: base/7/x86_64
```

At first I did this but I got the same error

```
[root@localhost ]# ONBOOT=no
[root@localhost ]# dhclient
[root@localhost ]# yum update
```

Then I went to /etc/yum.repos.d/

```
vi CentOS-Base.repo
```

and then I removed # before the baseurl and save it by :x and enter

now I get the following error

```
[root@localhost yum.repos.d]# yum update
Loaded plugins: fastestmirror, langpacks
Loading mirror speeds from cached hostfile
Could not retrieve mirrorlist http://mirrorlist.centos.org/?release=7&arch=x86_64&repo=os&infra=stock error was
14: curl#7 - "Failed to connect to 2001:1b48:203::4:10: Network is unreachable"
Could not retrieve mirrorlist http://mirrorlist.centos.org/?release=7&arch=x86_64&repo=extras&infra=stock error was
14: curl#7 - "Failed to connect to 2001:1b48:203::4:10: Network is unreachable"
Could not retrieve mirrorlist http://mirrorlist.centos.org/?release=7&arch=x86_64&repo=updates&infra=stock error was
14: curl#7 - "Failed to connect to 2001:1b48:203::4:10: Network is unreachable"
http://mirror.centos.org/centos/7/os/x86_64/repodata/repomd.xml: [Errno 14] curl#7 - "Failed to connect to 2607:f2d8:1:e::10: Network is unreachable"
Trying other mirror.
http://mirror.centos.org/centos/7/os/x86_64/repodata/repomd.xml: [Errno 14] curl#7 - "Failed to connect to 2607:f2d8:1:e::10: Network is unreachable"
Trying other mirror.
http://mirror.centos.org/centos/7/os/x86_64/repodata/repomd.xml: [Errno 14] curl#7 - "Failed to connect to 2607:f2d8:1:e::10: Network is unreachable"
Trying other mirror.
http://mirror.centos.org/centos/7/os/x86_64/repodata/repomd.xml: [Errno 14] curl#7 - "Failed to connect to 2607:f2d8:1:e::10: Network is unreachable"
Trying other mirror.
http://mirror.centos.org/centos/7/os/x86_64/repodata/repomd.xml: [Errno 14] curl#7 - "Failed to connect to 2607:f2d8:1:e::10: Network is unreachable"
Trying other mirror.
http://mirror.centos.org/centos/7/os/x86_64/repodata/repomd.xml: [Errno 14] curl#7 - "Failed to connect to 2607:f2d8:1:e::10: Network is unreachable"
Trying other mirror.
http://mirror.centos.org/centos/7/os/x86_64/repodata/repomd.xml: [Errno 14] curl#7 - "Failed to connect to 2607:f2d8:1:e::10: Network is unreachable"
Trying other mirror.
http://mirror.centos.org/centos/7/os/x86_64/repodata/repomd.xml: [Errno 14] curl#7 - "Failed to connect to 2607:f2d8:1:e::10: Network is unreachable"
Trying other mirror.
http://mirror.centos.org/centos/7/os/x86_64/repodata/repomd.xml: [Errno 14] curl#7 - "Failed to connect to 2607:f2d8:1:e::10: Network is unreachable"
Trying other mirror.
http://mirror.centos.org/centos/7/os/x86_64/repodata/repomd.xml: [Errno 14] curl#7 - "Failed to connect to 2607:f2d8:1:e::10: Network is unreachable"
Trying other mirror.


 One of the configured repositories failed (CentOS-7 - Base),
 and yum doesn't have enough cached data to continue. At this point the only
 safe thing yum can do is fail. There are a few ways to work "fix" this:

     1. Contact the upstream for the repository and get them to fix the problem.

     2. Reconfigure the baseurl/etc. for the repository, to point to a working
        upstream. This is most often useful if you are using a newer
        distribution release than is supported by the repository (and the
        packages for the previous distribution release still work).

     3. Run the command with the repository temporarily disabled
            yum --disablerepo=base ...

     4. Disable the repository permanently, so yum won't use it by default. Yum
        will then just ignore the repository until you permanently enable it
        again or use --enablerepo for temporary usage:

            yum-config-manager --disable base
        or
            subscription-manager repos --disable=base

     5. Configure the failing repository to be skipped, if it is unavailable.
        Note that yum will try to contact the repo. when it runs most commands,
        so will have to try and fail each time (and thus. yum will be be much
        slower). If it is a very temporary problem though, this is often a nice
        compromise:

            yum-config-manager --save --setopt=base.skip_if_unavailable=true

failure: repodata/repomd.xml from base: [Errno 256] No more mirrors to try.
http://mirror.centos.org/centos/7/os/x86_64/repodata/repomd.xml: [Errno 14] curl#7 - "Failed to connect to 2607:f2d8:1:e::10: Network is unreachable"
http://mirror.centos.org/centos/7/os/x86_64/repodata/repomd.xml: [Errno 14] curl#7 - "Failed to connect to 2607:f2d8:1:e::10: Network is unreachable"
http://mirror.centos.org/centos/7/os/x86_64/repodata/repomd.xml: [Errno 14] curl#7 - "Failed to connect to 2607:f2d8:1:e::10: Network is unreachable"
http://mirror.centos.org/centos/7/os/x86_64/repodata/repomd.xml: [Errno 14] curl#7 - "Failed to connect to 2607:f2d8:1:e::10: Network is unreachable"
http://mirror.centos.org/centos/7/os/x86_64/repodata/repomd.xml: [Errno 14] curl#7 - "Failed to connect to 2607:f2d8:1:e::10: Network is unreachable"
http://mirror.centos.org/centos/7/os/x86_64/repodata/repomd.xml: [Errno 14] curl#7 - "Failed to connect to 2607:f2d8:1:e::10: Network is unreachable"
http://mirror.centos.org/centos/7/os/x86_64/repodata/repomd.xml: [Errno 14] curl#7 - "Failed to connect to 2607:f2d8:1:e::10: Network is unreachable"
http://mirror.centos.org/centos/7/os/x86_64/repodata/repomd.xml: [Errno 14] curl#7 - "Failed to connect to 2607:f2d8:1:e::10: Network is unreachable"
http://mirror.centos.org/centos/7/os/x86_64/repodata/repomd.xml: [Errno 14] curl#7 - "Failed to connect to 2607:f2d8:1:e::10: Network is unreachable"
http://mirror.centos.org/centos/7/os/x86_64/repodata/repomd.xml: [Errno 14] curl#7 - "Failed to connect to 2607:f2d8:1:e::10: Network is unreachable"
```

I did use the following command too but the error was the same

```
yum clean all && yum clean metadata && yum clean dbcache && yum makecache && yum update -y
```

To check for the interent I did the following

[

```
root@localhost ~]# cat /etc/resolv.conf
; generated by /usr/sbin/dhclient-script
search dhcp.swmed.org
nameserver 199.242.236.1
nameserver 199.242.237.1
```

then I ping the first one and I recieve the folliwng message

```
[root@localhost ~]# ping 199.242.236.1
PING 199.242.236.1 (199.242.236.1) 56(84) bytes of data.
64 bytes from 199.242.236.1: icmp_seq=1 ttl=61 time=0.262 ms
64 bytes from 199.242.236.1: icmp_seq=2 ttl=61 time=0.315 ms
64 bytes from 199.242.236.1: icmp_seq=3 ttl=61 time=0.299 ms
64 bytes from 199.242.236.1: icmp_seq=4 ttl=61 time=0.351 ms
```

/etc?yum.repos.d/CentOS-Base.repo
is as follows

```
# CentOS-Base.repo
#
# The mirror system uses the connecting IP address of the client and the
# update status of each mirror to pick mirrors that are updated to and
# geographically close to the client.  You should use this for CentOS updates
# unless you are manually picking other mirrors.
#
# If the mirrorlist= does not work for you, as a fall back you can try the
# remarked out baseurl= line instead.
#
#

[base]
name=CentOS-$releasever - Base
mirrorlist=http://mirrorlist.centos.org/?release=$releasever&arch=$basearch&repo=os&infra=$infra
baseurl=http://mirror.centos.org/centos/$releasever/os/$basearch/
gpgcheck=1
gpgkey=file:///etc/pki/rpm-gpg/RPM-GPG-KEY-CentOS-7

#released updates
[updates]
name=CentOS-$releasever - Updates
mirrorlist=http://mirrorlist.centos.org/?release=$releasever&arch=$basearch&repo=updates&infra=$infra
baseurl=http://mirror.centos.org/centos/$releasever/updates/$basearch/
gpgcheck=1
gpgkey=file:///etc/pki/rpm-gpg/RPM-GPG-KEY-CentOS-7

#additional packages that may be useful
[extras]
name=CentOS-$releasever - Extras
mirrorlist=http://mirrorlist.centos.org/?release=$releasever&arch=$basearch&repo=extras&infra=$infra
baseurl=http://mirror.centos.org/centos/$releasever/extras/$basearch/
gpgcheck=1
gpgkey=file:///etc/pki/rpm-gpg/RPM-GPG-KEY-CentOS-7

#additional packages that extend functionality of existing packages
[centosplus]
name=CentOS-$releasever - Plus
mirrorlist=http://mirrorlist.centos.org/?release=$releasever&arch=$basearch&repo=centosplus&infra=$infra
baseurl=http://mirror.centos.org/centos/$releasever/centosplus/$basearch/
gpgcheck=1
enabled=0
```

Comment: Looks like "no Internet connection". Can you start e.g. `firefox` OK ? ... The mirror list seems OK. ( I'm using one of those. Today it's  http://mirror.netsite.dk/centos/7.5.1804/os/x86_64/ ).

Comment: @Knud Larsen  I am using the same machine to write here. so i do have internet. Can you please tell me how to use the link you gave me?

Comment: The link is a mirror, like the mirrors in the mirrorlist link that you provided. If you put http://centos.ca-west.mirror.fullhost.io/centos/7.5.1804/os/x86_64/ (which is the first mirror in the list you gave) and  mirror.netsite.dk/centos/7.5.1804/os/x86_64 (the link Knud provided) in a browser, they both work, and the results are essentially the same. This shows the mirrors do appear to be working. DNS is also working (2607:f2d8:1:e::10), but for some reason your machine is unable to connect to it. Everything seems to be working up to the point of making the connection.

Comment: @trogdor my question is that where should I amend in order to use the link you provided? can you give me an idea how to update the yum ?

Comment: Can you include the [base] section of /etc/yum.repos.d/CentOS-Base.repo in your question

Comment: nik : You can always use a fixed mirror. In the file `CentOS-Base.repo` comment out the mirrorlist line with a `#`. And "un comment" the `baseurl=` line. → In that line you can use any valid "repo URL" : `baseurl=http://mirror.netsite.dk/centos/7.5.1804/os/x86_64/` .... But I don't think that's the real issue. ... Curl corrupted? Or are you behind a proxy?

Comment: If you are internal to the University of Texas Southwestern Medical Center at Dallas it could be possible that the traffic is being blocked or that a proxy is causing trouble.

Comment: @trogdor I added it to my question

Comment: @Knud Larsen I am using proxy

Comment: "proxy" : No incoming traffic, no outgoing traffic : I guess you will have to open the door a bit more.

Comment: I added the other mirror to /etc/yum.repos.d/CentOS-Base.repo and I tried to update th yum but it gaves me the same error

Comment: @Knud Larsen  please tell me what I must do and I will do. I am at a university and they block everything. if I know what I need, I will ask the IT group for it

Answer (score 2):

Set proxy information in the /etc/yum.conf, like this:

```
proxy=http://xxx.xxx.xxx.xxx:1087
proxy_username=
proxy_password=
```

Answer (score 0):

I am also facing same issues on CentOS 7.5, After doing all debugging,  We found that Hardware Firewall is blocking Yum URLs.

After allowing the urls in firewall my problem has been resolved.